# ObjectOutputStream solo me instancia 1 objeto y me sobreescribe?

Tags: java

estoy realizando un ejercicio con ficheros binarios donde tengo un menú donde;

1. Puedo generar un fichero nuevo donde podré introducir alumnos y luego leerlos
2. Cargar un fichero para su uso, añadir alumnos y leerlos.
3. Añadir alumnos
4. Leerlos

El caso es que a la hora de añadir alumnos, solo me escribe 1 y no se van añadiendo y me lo sobreescribe porque al leerlo solo sale 1, y yo lo que quiero hacer es que cada vez que se añada 1 al leerlo me salgan todos

Estoy usando el ObjectOutputStream y no se que hacer para que no pase.

Mi main:

```
package tarea6;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

import tarea5.Alumno;
import utilidades.Entrada;

public class P06_tarea6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        boolean salida= false;
        boolean correcto= false;
        int entrada;
        String fvacio = null;
        String fseleccionado =null;
        File f0;
        
        int nia = 0;
        String nombre;
        String apellidos;
        char sexo = 0;
        String ciclo;
        String curso;
        String grupo;
        
        FileOutputStream fdatos=null;
        ObjectOutputStream datos=null;
        
        do {
            try {
                
                System.out.println("===MENU ALUMNOS ver.binario====");
                System.out.println("0 -Salir");
                System.out.println("1 -Generar fichero vacio (Si no se tiene se utilizará para trabajar)");
                System.out.println("2 -Seleccionar fichero existente (Para trabajar con el)");
                System.out.println("3 -Añadir ficha alumno");
                System.out.println("4 -Mostrar todos los alumnos");
                entrada=Entrada.entero();
                
                switch (entrada) {
                case 0:
                    salida=true;
                    System.out.println("Adios");
                
                    break;
                    
                case 1:
                    
                    do {
                        System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre y ruta para el fichero vacio");
                        fvacio=Entrada.cadena();
                        f0 = new File (fvacio);
                        
                        if (f0.exists() && f0.length()>1) {
                            System.out.println("Este fichero ya existe y tiene contenido, genere uno que no exista o uno sin contenido");
                            correcto=false;
                            
                        } else {
                            if (f0.createNewFile() || f0.length()==0) {
                                System.out.println("Generando Fichero..");
                                
                                
                                if (fseleccionado==null) {
                                    fseleccionado=fvacio;
                                    System.out.println("Se ha seleccionado este fichero para en sus siguientes modificaciones, si quiere cambiar de fichero seleccione 2 en el menú ");
                                    
                                    
                                } else {
                                    System.out.println("Se ha generado el fichero pero NO SE ESTÁ MODIFICANDO EN EL, para su asignación seleccione 2 en el menú");
                                    
                                }
                                correcto=true;
                            }
                        }
                    } while (correcto !=true);
                    
                    
                    
                    break;
                    
                    
                case 2:
                correcto=false;
                
                do {
                    System.out.println("Introduzca la ruta del fichero para su uso y modificarlo con las siguientes opciones");
                    fseleccionado=Entrada.cadena();
                    f0 = new File (fseleccionado);
                    
                    if (f0.isFile()) {
                        System.out.println("Está utilizando ahora el Fichero: "+f0.getAbsolutePath());
                        correcto=true;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Introduzca una ruta correcta!!");
                        correcto=false;
                    }
                } while (correcto!=true);
                
        
                    break;
                    
                case 3:
                    if (fseleccionado==null) {
                        System.out.println("No se ha cargado ninguna ficha para leer");
                    } else {
                        correcto=false;
                        fdatos = new FileOutputStream(fseleccionado);
                        datos = new ObjectOutputStream(fdatos);
                        DataOutputStream salidaDatos;
                        System.out.println("Este alumno se cargará en la ficha seleccionada");
                        salidaDatos=new DataOutputStream(fdatos);
                        do {
                        
                            try {
                                
                                
                                System.out.println("NIA: ");
                                nia=Entrada.entero();
                                correcto=true;
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                System.out.println("Tiene que ser un numero, introduzcalo de nuevo");
                            }
                        } while (correcto!=true);
                        correcto=false;
                        System.out.println("Nombre: ");
                        nombre=Entrada.cadena();
                        System.out.println("Apellidos: ");
                        apellidos=Entrada.cadena();
                        do {
                            try {
                                System.out.println("Genero? (H o M)");
                                sexo=Entrada.caracter();
                                
                                if (sexo!='H' && sexo!='M') {
                                    System.out.println("Introduzca (H o M) ");
                                } else {
                                    correcto=true;
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                System.out.println("Ha habido un error al introducir los datos, vuelva a introducirlos");
                            }
                        } while (correcto!=true);
                        System.out.println("Ciclo: ");
                        ciclo=Entrada.cadena();
                        System.out.println("Curso: ");
                        curso=Entrada.cadena();
                        System.out.println("Grupo: ");
                        grupo=Entrada.cadena();
                        
                        Alumno alumno = new Alumno(nia,nombre,apellidos,sexo,ciclo,curso,grupo);
                        
                        datos.writeObject(alumno);
                        datos.close();
                    }
                    
                    
                    break;
                    
                    
                case 4:
                    if (fseleccionado ==null) {
                        System.out.println("No se puede utilizar esta opción debido a que no tiene cargado ningun fichero");
                    } else {
                        FileInputStream fsalida = new FileInputStream(fseleccionado);
                        ObjectInputStream datosalida = new ObjectInputStream(fsalida);
                        
                        
                        try {
                            
                            while (datosalida.available() > -1) {
                                Alumno alumno = (Alumno) datosalida.readObject();
                                System.out.println("[Nia: "+alumno.getNia()+"] [Nombre: "+alumno.getNombre()+"] [Apellidos: "+alumno.getApellidos()+"] [Genero: "+alumno.getSexo()+"] [Ciclo: "+alumno.getCiclo()+"] [Curso: "+alumno.getCurso()+"] [Grupo: "+alumno.getGrupo()+"]");
                            }
                            
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("============");
                            System.out.println("Se llego al final del archivo");
                        } finally {
                            datosalida.close();
                        }
                        
                    
                    }
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    break;
                default: System.out.println("Introduzca bien el numero!");
                salida=false;
                    break;
                    
                    
                
                }
                
                
                
                
                
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Introduzca datos correctos o no se podrán realizar los pasos");
            salida=false;
            }
        } while (salida !=true);
    }

}
```

Mi clase alumno:

```
package primeraevaluacion;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Alumno implements Comparable<Alumno> ,Serializable{
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3494335033678429772L;
    /**
     * 
     */
    
    int Nia;
    public String Nombre;
    String Apellidos;
    char Sexo;
    String Ciclo;
    String Curso;
    
    
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Alumno [Nia=" + Nia + " "+ "Nombre=" + Nombre + ", Apellidos=" + Apellidos + ", Sexo=" + Sexo + ", Ciclo="
                + Ciclo + ", Curso=" + Curso + ", Grupo=" + Grupo + "]";
    }

    String Grupo;

    public Alumno(int Nia, String Nombre, String Apellidos, char sexo, String Ciclo, String Curso,
            String Grupo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        
        this.Nia=Nia;
        this.Nombre=Nombre;
        this.Apellidos=Apellidos;
        this.Sexo=sexo;
        this.Ciclo=Ciclo;
        this.Curso=Curso;
        this.Grupo=Grupo;
        
        
        
        
    }

    public Alumno() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Alumno o) {
        if (o.getNia() > Nia) {
            return -1;
        } else if (o.getNia()> Nia) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
        
    }
    
    

    public int getNia() {
        return Nia;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return Nombre;
    }

    public String getApellidos() {
        return Apellidos;
    }

    public char getSexo() {
        return Sexo;
    }

    public String getCiclo() {
        return Ciclo;
    }

    public String getCurso() {
        return Curso;
    }

    public String getGrupo() {
        return Grupo;
    }

    
}
```

Mi clase entrada (para leer de que tipo son las entradas, esta ni hace falta verla)

```
package utilidades;
import java.io.*;

public class Entrada {
    static String inicializar() {
        String buzon = "";
        InputStreamReader flujo = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader teclado = new BufferedReader(flujo);
        try {
            buzon = teclado.readLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.append("Entrada incorrecta)");
        }
        return buzon;
    }

    public static int entero() {
        int valor = Integer.parseInt(inicializar());
        return valor;
    }
    
    public static int entero(String mensaje) {
        int n=0;
        boolean correcto;
        do {
            correcto=true;
            System.out.print(mensaje);
            try {
                n=entero();
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("NÃºmero incorrecto. IntrodÃºzcalo de nuevo.");
                correcto=false;
            }
        }while(!correcto);
        return n;
    }

    public static double real() {
        double valor = Double.parseDouble(inicializar());
        return valor;
    }
    
    public static double real(String mensaje) {
        double n=0;
        boolean correcto;
        do {
            correcto=true;
            System.out.print(mensaje);
            try {
                n=real();
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("NÃºmero incorrecto. IntrodÃºzcalo de nuevo.");
                correcto=false;
            }
        }while(!correcto);
        return n;
    }

    public static String cadena() {
        String valor = inicializar();
        return valor;
    }

    public static char caracter() {
        String valor = inicializar();
        return valor.charAt(0);
    }
}
```

un saludo

Answer (score 0):

[`writeObject()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html)- escribe el objeto en el flujo de salida,de querer escribir mas de un objeto en el txt,lo que podrías realizar es guardar los objetos en una lista y escribir esta lista en el txt.

-Escribir:

```
List<Alumno> lista=new ArrayList<>(); //declaras la lista
Alumno alumno =new Alumno(nia,nombre,apellidos,sexo,ciclo,curso,grupo);//creas objeto
lista.add(alumno);//guardas el objeto en la lista
datos.writeObject(lista);escribes la lista
```

-Leer

```
     FileInputStream fsalida = new FileInputStream(fseleccionado);
       ObjectInputStream datosalida = new ObjectInputStream(fsalida);
       try {
       List<Alumno>p=(List<Alumno>)datosalida.readObject();//cast
//Impresion de datos
       p.forEach(alumno->System.out.println("[Nia: "+alumno.getNia()+"] [Nombre: "+alumno.getNombre()+"] [Apellidos: "+alumno.getApellidos()+"] [Genero: "+alumno.getSexo()+"] [Ciclo: "+alumno.getCiclo()+"] [Curso: "+alumno.getCurso()+"] [Grupo: "+alumno.getGrupo()+"]"));                
                                } catch (Exception e)
```